# Subset data with awk

Tags: awk

I want to subset data with awk. Let's say I have this file called test:

```
IP MAC Bandwidth etc etc

192.1.1.1 ff:ff:ff:ff 5.421M
192.1.2.3 ff:ff:ff:f3 5.120M
192.1.2.5 ff:ff:ff:f1 5.100M

stuff I don't want to be selected
```

I want to select just the bandwith values (much better if I can delete the M and the end, maybe with sed, I am not sure how, but that is not the main problem.)

The best subset I am doing for the moment is with:

```
awk '{print $3}' test
```

And the output is this:

```
Bandwidth

5.421M
5.120M
5.100M

dont
```

But I want it to be:

```
5.421
5.120
5.100
```

If the "M" is there it's not a problem but that is the idea. I have been collecting information about awk and trying stuff but haven't gotten to the solution.

Comment: Whats the 'stuff' you don't want selected ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact answer requires that you specify your problem a bit more.  However, the general syntax of an awk statement is:

```
PATTERN { ACTION }
```

ACTION will only be executed for lines that match PATTERN. Thus, we can use `PATTERN` to subset by row, and the ACTION block to subset by column.  For instance, given your input, I might use the following:

```
> awk '/^[0-9]/ {print $3 }' INPUTFILE
5.421M
5.120M
5.100M
```

the `PATTERN` here is a regular expression that matches any line where the first character is an integer from 0 to 9.  To remove the `M` you could either pipe this to another command such as `tr` or use the `gsub` command as in 
cuonglm's answer

```
awk '/^[0-9]/ { gsub(/M/, "", $3); print $3 }' INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: You can also use +<FIELD> to remove characters after a number such as `awk '/^[0-9]/{print +$3}'` although this will remove unnecessary 0s. To keep formatting use  `awk '/^[0-9]/ {printf("%.3f\n",+$3)}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all thing that are not digit or dot before printing:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[^[:digit:].]/,"",$3);print $3}' file
5.421
5.120
5.100
```

Comment: I dont why that gives me the same output as awk '{print $3}' test

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intend to make some operation with text the `sed` usage seems is more resonable

```
sed -En 's/.* (\S+)M$/\1/p'
```

`-E`  let's to avoid meta-characters usage with backslash (`\(, \+,` etc.)

`-n`  suppress output exept ordered by `p`

`s/` substitute

`.*` first part of the line for space (the last space becouse greedy)

`()` "revers link" - you can call pattern inside brackets by `\number`

`\S` every non-space simbol (everything exept `:blank:`)

`+` one or more previous simbol

`M$` "M" at the end of line

`/p` print line where substitution is made

Meaning is "Substitute whole line by pattern inside brackets and print lines where such substitution is made only"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution with awk but this worked:

```
cat test |grep ":"| cut -f3 -d " " | sed 's/[MGB]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use match function in awk as well.

```
awk '{match($3, /[0-9]+.[0-9]+/,arr)}{ print arr[0]}' file
```

Comment: Please say `gawk` if using `gawk`-features.